# Simple question COQ

Tags: coq, proof-assistants, inductive-datatypes

I'm a beginner in the coq proof assistant, so sorry if my question is silly. I would like to prove properties of a mathematical object. For clarity I will describe an over-simplified version of my object. Intuitively, the object has
three sets A, B, C. The list A is of the form 
$$A= \{(0,x_1) (0,x_2), ... ,(0,x_n)\}$$ i.e, all pairs consist of the number zero and an arbitrary number. Analogously, the set B is of the form 
$$B = \{(1,y_1)(1,y_2)...(1,y_m)\}$$. And the set $C$ is such that C = A U B. 
For concreteness the sets $A,B,C$ can be defined as lists, if for some reason it is not inconvenient in Coq

So the simplified object would be of the following form:

Object

A : Set of elements of the form (0,x) where x is some number

B : Set of elements of the form (1,y) where x is some number

C : Set such that C = A U B

The Condition that the structure must satisfy is:

If (0,a) belongs to A then (1,a) belongs to B.

**Questions:**

1) How do I define a type consisting of pairs in which the 
first element is 0 and the second an arbitrary natural number?
(Obs: This was answered by @KonstantinWeitz but his answer received 
a minus. Why wouldn't Konstantin's answer be satisfactory in Coq?)

2)How do I define the object above in coq? I tried to do it with records.
But the problem is that I have no idea of how to define a type of question 1.

3) How to I impose the condition that this object is valid only if for 
each (0,x_n) in A there is a (1,y_n) in B with y_n=x_n? And the condition
that $C = A \cup B$?

Comment: I think this is on-topic. Yes, Coq proofs are very similar to programming but I guarantee that this question would not be answered on [SO]. Indeed, if it were posted there, they'd punt it straight back here.

Comment: You do not want to do 1). What are registers in Coq?

Comment: Please restrict yourself to one question per post. Also, note that this is close to "tech support" for Coq; maybe a mailing list or board dedicated to Coq is the better address? [cs.SE] is mostly about implementation-agnostic principles; there may be such in your question which you should then point out.

Comment: @Raphael, if you insist, I believe that the point here is how to map very simple set theoretic constructions to the calculus of inductive constructions...

Comment: @AndrejBauer. That is something I don't understand. Why would question 1 be so weird in coq's world? With respect to registers, I was meaning Record. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Because you should use sum types in Coq to "tag" things, not numbers like 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2):

Set-theoretic thinking is creating trouble, as you are trying
to do things in non-Coq ways. Let me show you a solution which
works better, and then you can explain what your actual non-simplified
problem is -- we can probably optimize that one to.

If we have two lists `A` and `B` then we do not have to tag the elements
of the first list with 0 and the second one with 1. That is, rather
than having

> `A = [(0,x_1), ..., (n,x_n)]` and `B = [(1,y_1), ..., (m, y_m)]`

we can equivalently have just

> `A = [x_1, ..., x_n]` and `B = [y_1, ..., y_m]`.

So, we are really trying to define:

> *A pair of lists such that the elements of the first one are contained in the second one.*

We are going to use the standard library for lists (by the way
if you are simulating sets by using lists, you shouldn't).

```
Require Import List.

(* We define what it means for the elements of list X to be
   contained in list Y. *)
Definition contained_in {T} (X : list T) (Y : list T) :=
   forall x, In x X -> In x Y.

(* Now we define our data structure. It is a Record with three fields. *)
Record MyLists := {
  A : list nat;
  B : list nat;
  valid : contained_in A B
}.

(** For example, suppose we want to construct A = [1,2,3] and B = [2,3,3,1,5]. *)
Definition example : MyLists.
Proof.
  (* We give Coq the fields we know about. *)
  refine {| A := 1::2::3::nil ; B := 2::3::3::1::5::nil |}.
  (* Coq tells us we also have to provide the 'valid' field. *)
  (* We tell Coq to do it itself. *)
  firstorder.
Defined.
```

Comment: I don't think (Coq) code has any business being here, but the rest of the answer seems strong to me. So, if you must.... \*theatrical sigh\*

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thank you for your answer. The structure I have in mind is application specific, so I will skip its precise definition. The idea is that I would like it to be as concrete as possible. For this reason, I would like to have a list A (regarded as a set) such that A=[(0,x_1),...,(0,x_n)] and another list B = [(1,y_1),...,(1,y_m)]. For instance, In the same structure I would need to have a third set C = A U B. I will edit the question to be a bit more precise.

Comment: Are you ever going to mix the lists $A$ and $B$? Is that why you are tagging them, so they don't get confused? Well, in that case you should use a sum type instead of set-theoretic tags.

Comment: @Raphael: You can look at this as a lesson in how not to do set theory in type theory.

Comment: This is a meta-discussion, but I think that Coq code has much reason to be here on CS, even if it has no reason being here in the answer to this question. If giving a proof is a good answer, giving a machine-checkable proof is a GREAT answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
Require Import List.

Definition Singleton (n:nat) := {n':nat | n' = n}.   (* 1) *)

Definition zero : Singleton 0. compute. eauto. Defined.
Definition one : Singleton 1. compute. eauto. Defined.

Record MyLists := {   (* 2) *)
  A : list ((Singleton 0) * nat);
  B : list ((Singleton 1) * nat);
  valid : forall n, In (zero,n) A -> In (one,n) B   (* 3) *)
}.
```